# Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Errors

Tags: xcode

Xcode gives me 3 "Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error" errors.  But, when I click them it doesn't direct me to a line in my code, so I don't know what/where the problem is.  I know others have asked this question, but all of the solutions that I could find were specific to each individual's code.  I am learning C++, so these errors are coming as part of a beginner program I'm working on.

**Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error
  "SensorNode::SensorNode(char*, float, float, float, int, float)", referenced from:
  Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error
  "LOCATION::LOCATION()", referenced from:
  Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error
  Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

If it helps, I'll put my code here:
here's `my "sensor_node.h"`

```
#ifndef SENSORNODE_H
#define SENSORNODE_H

#include <iostream>

class LOCATION {
    float lat, longi, height;

public:
    LOCATION ();
    void setx(float xx);
    void sety(float yy);
    void setz(float zz);
    void print();
};

class SensorNode {
    char* NodeName;
    int NodeID;
    LOCATION Node1;
    float batt;
    int func;


public:
    SensorNode(char *n, float x, float y, float z, int i, float ah);
    void print();
    void setOK(int o);
    int getOK();
    void setLOC(float longi, float lat, float h);
};

#endif /* defined(__Project_3__sensor_node__) */
```

here's my sensor_node.cpp:

```
#include "sensor_node.h"
//#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void LOCATION::setx(float xx) {
    lat = xx;
    if (lat > 180.0 || lat < -180.0) {
        cout << "Latitude is not in the -180 to 180 degree range";
        lat = 0.0;
    }
}

void LOCATION::sety(float yy) {
    longi = yy;
    if (longi > 180.0 || longi < -180.0) {
        cout << "Latitude is not in the -180 to 180 degree range";
        longi = 0.0;
    }


}
void LOCATION::setz(float zz) {
    height = zz;
}

void LOCATION::print() {

    cout << "(LONGITUDE: " << longi << " ,LATITUDE: " << lat << " ,HEIGHT: " << height << " )";
}
```

and here's my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "sensor_node.h"

int main() {

    LOCATION a; SensorNode s1("Pulse",15.9,-30.1,0,157,2.0);

    cout << "Beginning LOCATION tests.\n\n";
    cout << "  After initial construction:  ";
    a.print();
    cout << "\n";
    a.setx(-45.3);
    a.sety(27.6);
    a.setz(3.5);
    cout << "  After setting x/y/z to -45.3/27.6/3.5:  ";
    a.print();
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "  After attempting to set longitude to 180.1:  ";
    a.setx(180.1);
    a.print();
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "  After attempting to set longitude to -180.1:  ";
    a.setx(-180.1);
    a.print();
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "  After attempting to set latitude to 180.1:  ";
    a.sety(180.1);
    a.print();
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "  After attempting to set latitude to -180.1:  ";
    a.sety(-180.1);
    a.print();
    cout << "\n";
/*
    cout << "\n\n\n\nBeginning sensor node tests.\n\n";
    cout << "  After initial construction:";
    s1.print();
    cout << "\n  Printing the value returned by getOK: " << s1.getOK();
    cout << "\n  After changing location to 20/30/40:";
    s1.setLOC(20,30,40);
    s1.print();
    cout << "\n  After trying to set location illegally:";
    s1.setLOC(181, -181, 10);
    s1.print();
    cout << "\n  Node fails, then try to change location:";
    s1.setOK(0);
    s1.setLOC(5,10,15);
    s1.print();
    cout << "\n  Printing the value returned by getOK: " << s1.getOK();
    cout << "\n\n\n  End of tests.\n";

    cout << "Enter an integer to quit: ";
    cin >> hold;
*/
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't written the constructor for the `LOCATION` class. You declare a `LOCATION` named `a` and a `SensorNode` which contains a `LOCATION`, but the linker can't figure out where the code for the `LOCATION` constructor is, so it can't link. Write a constructor for the `LOCATION` class and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have forgotten to implement `SensorNode`. In SensorNode.h you declare a class, `SensorNode` which has data and public methods, but in SensorNode.cpp you are not providing an implementation of `SensorNode` (constructor), `print` etc. The linker is unable to find implementations of these since they haven't been implemented, hence the linker error.

Here's some  boilerplate you can start out with:

```
SensorNode::SensorNode(char *n, float x, float y, float z, int i, float ah)
{
}

void SensorNode::print()
{
}

void SensorNode::setOK(int o)
{
}

int SensorNode::getOK()
{
}

void SensorNode::setLOC(float longi, float lat, float h)
{
}
```

Comment: Oh ok!  Thanks so much Muncken!  I though because I had commented out the SensorNode tests I could test out just the Location stuff, but I see that it calls the sensor node stuff in the first line of the main.  Thanks so much for your help and for the boilerplate code!

Comment: I put in the boiler code, and then commented out the second half of that first line (because I'm trying to test the Location class) and I still get two Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Errors.              Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "LOCATION::LOCATION()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
      SensorNode::SensorNode(char*, float, float, float, int, float) in sensor_node.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
any thoughts?

Comment: Turns out it was that I didn't have a constructor for the LOCATION class that was causing the Apple Mach-O Linker errors.  So once I did that it ran fine.  Thank you so much for the boilerplate code though!  very helpful for my later stuff

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out.